# How do I instrument region and environment information correctly in Prometheus?

Tags: go, prometheus, metrics, promql

I've an application, and I'm running one instance of this application per AWS region.
I'm trying to instrument the application code with Prometheus metrics client, and will be exposing the collected metrics to the `/metrics` endpoint. There is a central server which will scrape the `/metrics` endpoints across all the regions and will store them in a central Time Series Database.

Let's say I've defined a metric named: `http_responses_total` then I would like to know its value aggregated over all the regions along with individual regional values.
How do I store this `region` information which could be any one of the 13 regions and `env` information which could be `dev` or `test` or `prod` along with metrics so that I can slice and dice metrics based on `region` and `env`?

I found a few ways to do it, but not sure how it's done in general, as it seems a pretty common scenario:

- Storing `region` and `env` info as labels with each of the metrics (not recommended: https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#target-labels-not-static-scraped-labels)
- Using target labels - I have `region` and `env` value with me in the application and would like to set this information from the application itself instead of setting them in scrape config
- Keeping a separate gauge metric to record `region` and `env` info as labels (like described here: https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-the-software-version-to-prometheus) - this is how I'm planning to store my application `version` info in tsdb but the difference between app `version` info and `region` info is: the version keeps changing across releases however region is which I get from the config file is constant. So, not sure if this is a good way to do it.

I'm new to Prometheus. Could someone please suggest how I should store this `region` and `env` information? Are there any other better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the proposed options will work, and all of them have downsides.

The **first** option (having `env` and `region` exposed by the application with every metric) is easy to implement but hard to maintain. Eventually somebody will forget to about these, opening a possibility for an unobserved failure to occur. Aside from that, you may not be able to add these labels to other exporters, written by someone else. Lastly, if you have to deal with millions of time series, more plain text data means more traffic.

The **second*** option (adding these labels with Prometheus as a part of scrape configuration) is what I would choose. To save the words, consider this monitoring setup:

| Datacenter Prometheus | Regional Prometheus | Global Prometheus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. Collects metrics from local instances. 2. Adds `dc` label to each metric. 3. Pushes the data into the regional Prometheus -> | 1. Collects data on datacenter scale. 2. Adds `region` label to all metrics. 3. Pushes the data into the global instance -> | Simply collects and stores the data on global scale |

> *see note below

The **third** option (storing these labels in a separate metric) will make it quite difficult to write and understand queries. Take this one for example:

```
sum by(instance) (node_arp_entries) and on(instance) node_exporter_build_info{version="0.17.0"}
```

It calculates a `sum` of `node_arp_entries` for instances with node-exporter `version="0.17.0"`. Well more specifically it calculates a sum for every instance and then just drops those with a wrong version, but you got the idea.

---

**OPTION 2** is the kind of setup you need on Google scale, but the point is the simplicity. It's perfectly clear where each label comes from and why. This approach requires you to make Prometheus configuration somewhat more complicated, and the less Prometheus instances you have, the more scrape configurations you will need. **Overall, I think, this option beats the alternatives.**

Comment: thanks for the answer. Have a few follow-up questions:
1. > "less Prometheus instances you have, the more scrape configurations you will need"
Didn't get this. Could you please clarify?
2. Should I also keep the app `version` information in the scrape config instead of in a dedicated metric's label?
3. Are there any other better ways to do this that you're aware of apart from these three?

Comment: @Romy 1. There is a nice feature that allows Prometheus to add a set of labels before pushing data into a remote storage (other Prometheus for example). If you collect all data with just one Prometheus, you have to add those labels either per machine or per scrape job. This is just more work than simply adding labels to everything during export. 2. No, this is best to have as described in the opt3. It's unlikely that you'll need  details by version, because you probably have just one version at a time. 3. No, I would have mentioned otherwise. I use the opt2 in prod.